# Autocomplete using nested form on has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, getter-setter

I'm currently using the nested_form gem (Ryan Bates) to add ingredients to a recipe using a nested form.  All works well.  My next goal is to add autocomplete to ingredients, but I'm stuck on how I should set this up.

A recipe can have many ingredients, and an ingredient can have many recipes.  I'm using a has_many :through relationship to manage the logic.

**recipe.rb**

```
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  attr_accessible :name, :desc, :ingredients_attributes

  validates_presence_of :name
```

**ingredient.rb**

```
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

  attr_accessible :name, :protein, :carbs, :fat, :ingredient_name

  validates_presence_of :name, :protein, :carbs, :fat

  def ingredient_name
    try(:name)
  end

  def ingredient_name=(name)
    Ingredient.find_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

**recipe_ingredient.rb**

```
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  attr_accessible :ingredient_id

  validates_presence_of :ingredient_id, :recipe_id
```

**recipes/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'eg. Fajita Magic Sunrise' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :desc, 'Description' %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :desc, rows: 5, placeholder: 'Steps are useful here...' %>
  </div>

  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
      <%= render "ingredient_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Ingredient", :ingredients %></p>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, class: 'button green' %> or <%= link_to 'go back', :back %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**recipes/_ingredient_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :ingredient_name, placeholder: 'Eg. 1 Scrambled Egg' %> 
  <%= f.text_field :protein, placeholder: "Protein", size: 5 %>
  <%= f.text_field :carbs, placeholder: "Carbs", size: 5 %>
  <%= f.text_field :fat, placeholder: "Fat", size: 5 %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
</div>
```

**development.log (when trying to add ingredients)**

```
Started PUT "/recipes/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-10 12:53:15 -0600
Processing by RecipesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "recipe"=>{"name"=>"Next Recipe", "desc"=>"Only one ingredient", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"new_1331405592002"=>{"ingredient_name"=>"Beans", "protein"=>"", "carbs"=>"", "fat"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Recipe", "id"=>"7"}
  Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://***.dev/recipes/7
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

So!  As you can see I set a new attribute named ingredient_name, and created a getter/setter method in ingredients.rb to pull it and set it if it exists.  Basically, I think the problem is that I'm using has_many :through.

It doesn't seem that what I have now would update the join table because the recipe isn't being passed to my setter method, so it wouldn't know which recipe to save it to anyway.

So does the virtual attribute then need to be in the recipe model?  As you can see, just really confused.

Comment: I don't think the setter method is even firing off in the implementation above.  I've added a logger to it just to inspect what's going on, and even removed it, and no errors are thrown.  I'm beginning to think that I'm using the wrong method name for the setter.

Comment: Added a development.log snippet.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: did you got the answer or resolved the problem?